# SoundPool with ImageView Usage Like Switch

Tags: android, kotlin, soundpool

im stuck while coding my app and i couldn't find any source for solve that problem.

Problem : I want to use an imageview as switch. When i click to imageView i want to start my SoundPool.Player and if i click again to imageView then it should be stop.

I can start sounds when i click to imageView but i can't stop it.

```
class PlayerPool() {

lateinit var poolPlayer : SoundPool
var playerId : Int = 0

companion object {

    const val pageTag = "PlayerPool"
    var instance: PlayerPool? = null

    fun getInstance(context:Context): PlayerPool? {
        if(instance == null)
            instance = PlayerPool()
        return instance
    }

}

fun poolStarter(ctx : Context, position: Int){

    poolPlayer = SoundPool.Builder().setMaxStreams(10).build()
    val poolSounds = poolPlayer.load(ctx,position,1)

    poolPlayer.setOnLoadCompleteListener { soundPool, sampleId, status ->

        playerId = poolPlayer.play(poolSounds, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1, 0, 1f)

    }

}

fun poolPausePlayer(){

        poolPlayer.stop(playerId)

}
```

}

```
class MixFragmentAdapter(
val mixList: ArrayList<SoundModel>,
val mixListener:RowClickListener<SoundModel>
) : BaseRecyclerAdapter<SoundModel,RowFragmentMixBinding>() {

override val layoutRes: Int
    get() = R.layout.row_fragment_mix
override val arrayList: ArrayList<SoundModel>
    get() = mixList

override fun bindView(
    binding: RowFragmentMixBinding,
    currentData: SoundModel,
    position: Int
) {

    binding.ivMixCardImages.setImageResource(mixList[position].soundImage)
    binding.root.setOnClickListener {

        mixListener.onClick(position, item = mixList[position])

        binding.switchMusicControl.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->

            if (isChecked){

                PlayerPool.getInstance(binding.ivMixCardImages.context)!!.poolStarter(binding.ivMixCardImages.context,position)

            }
            else{

                PlayerPool.getInstance(binding.ivMixCardImages.context)!!.poolPausePlayer()

            }


        }


    }
}
```

}

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="6dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#7E57C2"
    app:cardElevation="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvMixSounds" >
    
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivMixCardImages"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tvCardInformation"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvMixCardInformation"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_fire" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvMixCardInformation"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:text="Ateş!"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/ivMixCardImages"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/switchMusicControl"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: To determine if the problem is related with the click or with something else do something like this `lifeCycleScope.launch { delay(2000) PlayerPool.getI...//the pause }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a common issue for those using soundpool for the first time. if you look carefully at the docs for soundpool, play uses the parameter "soundID", while stop uses the parameter "streamID". it's easy to overlook this and use the soundID returned from the load function for both commands, as your code does. i've even seen android tutorial examples get this wrong. instead use these commands:

```
s1 = sound.load(Main.this, R.raw.mosq1, 1);  
if (l1==true){p1=sound.play(s1, 1, 1, 0, rep, 1);     
sound.stop(p1);
```

must ensure `p1` is right.

About your code :

```
    fun poolStarter(ctx : Context, position: Int){
    ....
    poolPlayer.setOnLoadCompleteListener { soundPool, sampleId, status ->

        playerId = poolPlayer.play(poolSounds, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1, 0, 1f)

    }}

    fun poolPausePlayer(){
            poolPlayer.stop(playerId)
    }
```

when you use , must ensure playerId is the same.

try change your code in MixFragmentAdapter:

```
    lateinit var p:PlayerPool
    override fun bindView(
        binding: RowFragmentMixBinding,
        currentData: SoundModel,
        position: Int
    ) {

        var context = binding.ivMixCardImages.context
        p =PlayerPool.getInstance(context)!!
        binding.ivMixCardImages.setImageResource(mixList[position].soundImage)
        binding.root.setOnClickListener {
            mixListener.onClick(position, item = mixList[position])
            binding.switchMusicControl.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
                if (isChecked){
                    p.poolStarter(context, position )
                }
                else{
                    p.poolPausePlayer()
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Excuse me, i've tried your code sample. "p.poolStarter()" is returning "kotlin.unit" instead of Int . I couldn't solve what is wrong, im newbie in coding by the way. To be honestly im so confused because i can't find any documentation about SoundPool as good enough.

Comment: Change `p:PlayerPool` to a global variable and initialize it outside is fine. Have updated the code may fix the problem. But "p.poolStarter()" seems dont have a return,  could post the code or error log if problems happen.